# When to elicit user feedback on search results

Tags: popup, workflow, ratings, user-feedback, lightbox

I am working on a product that provides investigative leads based on a search. We are trying to assess the helpfulness of the leads. Previously we had a good/bad option always present at the top of the page, and when a user is ready to archive the entire search we prompt them to answer the simple good/bad question and then offer space to enter additional comments. The static option gets ignored and the pop-up gets a false response.

The problem I'm facing is that at the point of archiving, they have forgotten whether the leads were helpful and are just trying to "clear their desk". And at the point of returning results to their search, they don't know if they're helpful yet. The work they do to validate the leads takes them out of the application. So at what point is it least intrusive to prompt them to provide feedback?

Comment: Why don't you talk to your users to find out when would be a good time in their process / day to ask them? And what method to use.Is necessary to do it in product, in context — i.e. are you looking to validate the usefulness of specific results? Are you looking for quantitative data?

Or could you do you with a longer term "average", and/or attitude based feedback? Like asking your users how often the results are "good/bad"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit vague without any pictures, but I think I get the gist of what you mean.

Let me share with you a case from a few years ago.

At that time, we needed to optimize the search function on an e-commerce platform, and we wanted to know whether the recommendation algorithm of the search was accurate, so we hoped our customers to give us some feedback.

We do not consider useful and useless to be of value to us, we want to get some real feedback. Sounds a little similar to yours?

After several rounds of experimentation, we changed our strategy and no longer put feedback at the top of the page.

After the user has performed several searches (2 or 3 or more, depending on the algorithm), we insert an item into the search results asking the customer if there was a problem with the search.

If the user clicks yes, we will provide an input box to ask them to leave their feedback.

Compared to the previous approach, this is more in line with the situation of the user at that time, and it will be easier to obtain the empathy of the user.